# reverse print without trailing

Tags: bash, csv, awk

I have a bash file calling a dns zone and have piped out the `fqdn` which I need to output in reverse.

The snippet below does that fine except I get a trialing `.` at the end which I don't want creating an import, csv (comma delimiter) format:

```
... | awk -F'.' '{for (i=NF;i>0;i--){printf $i"."};printf "\n"}'
```

example source:

```
abc.def,ghi.com
hjd.dhjs.dhuj.oiuehj.ksjdhf.com
```

desired results:

```
com.ghi.def.abc
com.ksjdhf.oiuehj.dhuj.dhjs.hjd
```

current results:

```
com.ghi.def.abc.
com.ksjdhf.oiuehj.dhuj.dhjs.hjd.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one approach:

```
awk -F'.' '{for (i=NF;i>1;i--){printf $i"."};print $1}'
```

Sample usage:

```
$ echo abc.def.ghi.com | awk -F'.' '{for (i=NF;i>1;i--){printf $i"."};print $1}' 
com.ghi.def.abc
```

Explanation:

- `for (i=NF;i>1;i--){printf $i"."`

  This prints the parts in reverse, starting at `$NF` and stopping at `$2` (the second field), with each part followed by a period.
- `print $1`

  This prints the final part without a trailing period.  Because `print` is used here, rather than `printf`, there is no need for an explicit newline.

#### Alternative

For variety, here is another solution:

```
awk -F'.' '{s=""; for (i=NF;i>0;i--){s=s"."$i};print substr(s,2)}'
```

This uses the same logic as the original post: one loop over all parts.  Rather than printing at each step, though, this saves the desired output into string `s`.  At the end it prints `s` except for the last character which would be the superfluous period.

#### Alternative using `tac` rather than `awk`

```
$ echo abc.def.ghi.com | tr '.' '\n' | tac | tr '\n' '.' | sed 's/\.$/\n/'
com.ghi.def.abc
```

Or, even simpler:

```
$ echo  abc.def.ghi.com | tac -s'[.\n]' 
abc.def.ghi.com
```

Comment: Any chance you can explain why `$1` works over `"\n"`?

Comment: @MichaelFrank I updated the answer with some explanation.  Briefly, the difference is that the loop stops at `i==2`.  Thus, when the loop ends, `$1` still needs to be printed and we print it without the superfluous trailing period.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `printf` with another variable: the character to print after each field.

```
$ awk -F"[.,]" '{for (i=NF;i>0;i--) printf "%s%s", $i, (i==1?"\n":".")}' file
com.ghi.def.abc
com.ksjdhf.oiuehj.dhuj.dhjs.hjd
```

- `-F"[.,]"` sets the field separator to either `.` or `,`. This way, each single word will count as a different field.
- `(i==1?"\n":".")` means: in case `i` is `1`, then use `\n`; otherwise, use `.`.